# Generic solution to disable server side validation from client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a scenario as such.

Two divs that contain two different DropDownLists. Both of these divs visibility is controlled *client side* by two independent checkboxes and both of the DropDownLists have required field validators which I expect to be disabled when the divs are hidden (ie: the checkboxes unchecked).

So knowing there was a method that allowed you to disable a field validator client side I did a quick search and re-found `ValidatorEnable(Validator, Boolean);`. After wiring everything up my client side validation would successfully be ignored in cases where the checkbox was unchecked BUT the problem was once I hit the server side.

Using a typical scenario on the server like such

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid) 
    {

    }
}
```

On the server side - much to my surprize as my gut told me this should effect both sides - the page validation would continue to report `IsValid = false`. So I ran some tests with the following code...

```
$(Page_Validators).each(function (index, value) {
    ValidatorEnable(value, false);
});
```

And quickly confirmed that infact the ValidatorEnable method does only affect client side validation and leaves the server side state of the field validators untouched.

Now I could probably think of a couple of ways off the top of my head to "hackaly" deal with this issue. For example: Check the checkbox state on postback and disable the validators as required, set some hidden field etc.. but the problem is that I am using this functionality in an **extremely large** project and the standard that I apply will be used in all future forms.

So basically I am hoping to find a generic solution that doesn't require major alterations to the typical simplicity that the field validators in ASP.NET provide. Any ideas?

PS: Just realized that if I'm not careful with this I would potentially introduce a security vulnerability right? Thats probably why Microsoft didn't do it by default.

Comment: Before I got to your PS, that's all I was thinking of. The server side validation can be *trusted* because there's nothing the client can do to circumvent it. The client side validation is just for convenience.

Comment: I don't see anything hacky about disabling the validator as per the state of the check box. That is your application logic right? If check box is unchecked, disable the validator.

Comment: Fair point on both parts. I however would argue that an 'opt in' policy for this functionality could still be safe and I guess you're right, it isn't too bad to just check the checkbox state but over a project with a couple of hundred thousand lines (That you're writing independently), every saved line is a godsend.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach could be used by using a hidden field for each validator and through client side input, manipulations, or whatever you want, just fill in some custom values, say true and false, in those hidden fields through javascript.

When the form is posted back, you can check the hidden field values for true or false and depending on those, you can enable or disable your server-side validator.